# How to find out what database to look for the login authentication

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a project that has a website panel and an android app and for database i'm using mysql to save users information like username and password.

What i'm going to do is for every client(company), i want to create a database with it's unique name but with same tables and my problem is when users are logging in, i don't know how to find out which database should i use for login authentication because i think it's a bad idea to look in the all of databases to find user's information.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: why you don't add a 'company' column in your user table ? for every different company, a different 'company' value.

Comment: Because if i do so then i have to ask users to choose their company when they are registering and i'm not sure if its a good idea when there are a lot of companies and they have to search among them to find their own company. What if they choose wrong company on purpose or accidentally ? but it seems i don't have any other choice, right ?

Comment: You can juste set the company name in your app. For the company 'a' you make your app fill the field with 'a' and you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: Create API for connect Android User to Mysql user+database,
so when you authenticate, the API send you back the connection string, different for every user. It means that you need a database, only for auth and connect.

Comment: Ok but how can i know what connection string i should send back based on user's username when i don't know his/her company ? is the only option is to save their companies in user table and ask users to choose their company on register page like what @tomtomtom said ?

Comment: Use a specific table to connect user for companies, somehow you need to give them a register page, so you can connect companies / databases to users.